# Given matrices $A$ and $B$ solve for $P^{-1}AP=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given
$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$ and
$B=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 & 3\\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$. Find $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=B$.

Initially I wanted to set this up in the same way you would solve this as a eigenvectors/diagonalizable problem. Since $B$ is not a diagonal matrix, setting the columns of $P$ as the eigenvectors won't help us.

One thing that I noticed is that $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues.  (I am not sure if this is important or not.)

Comment: if $QBQ^{-1}=RAR^{-1}$, then $B=Q^{-1}RAR^{-1}Q=P^{-1}AP$ with $P=R^{-1}Q$

Comment: don't see how this helps me solve for $P$. As I would need to guess and check until I get two matrices that work

Comment: if you know how to diagonalize $A$ and $B$, you don't need to "guess and check"

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Im just a bit confused by how you got $QBQ^{-1}=RAR^{-1}$. We know that the diagonal matrix is $D = Q^{-1}AQ$ and $D = R^{-1}BR$. Putting this together gives us $Q^{-1}AQ = R^{-1}BR \iff RQ^{-1}AQR^{-1} = B$. But that is different then what you used.

Comment: Your $Q$ is the inverse of my $R$.  Using your notation, we have $Q^{-1}AQ=R^{-1}BR$, so $P^{-1}AP=B$ when $P=QR^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarity is an equivalence relation on the space of square matrices.

If you can diagonalize $A$ and $B$ to the same matrix $D=Q^{-1}AQ=R^{-1}BR$,

then $RQ^{-1}AQR^{-1}=B$, so take $P=QR^{-1}$.

You can change coordinates from one basis to another

if you can change both of them to eigenvector coordinates.